# MD5 Checksum differes from browser to Node js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, checksum, cryptojs

I am trying to perform a checksum on a file with javascript. I'm using a FileReader and using CryptoJS with the .MD5 method as well as the CryptoJS.enc.Hex encoding.

The checksums differ from the front end (above) and on the back end, where I am getting it from ExpressFIleUpload and also generated my own with the crypto module via crypto.createHash('md5') and getting a digest via hash.digest('hex'); and out of those two, (my own and ExpressFileUpload) they too, differ..

what is going on..?

```js
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.file = data;

        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function (someelement) {
            return function (e) {
                let md5 = CryptoJS.MD5(e.target.result);
                let str = md5.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
                console.log('str', str); // will give one random md5
            };
        })(img);

        reader.readAsBinaryString(data);
```

then on the server using https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

```js
export async function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.files.file.md5) // some other md5
  
  const hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
  let buff = Buffer.from(req.files.file.data, "base64").toString('utf-8');

  // edit, this actually DOES come to the same if I remove 
  // .toString('utf-8')
  // as the req.files.file.md5

  hash.update(buff);

  let str = hash.digest("hex");
  console.log('other hash', str); // and some third completely different md5
}
```

can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you encode the e.target.result to UTF-8 in your front-end? I had kind of like the same problem, but then I realized, that I'd used the wrong encoding.

Try to encode your Plain String into utf-8 and hash it after that.

Comment: I just tried, and it didn't work.. front end md5 is still different than backend md5 :\

Comment: Have you tried to compare it manually? Like opening the original file and the uploaded file in an editor and comparing them? Maybe the data is corrupted.

Comment: yeah, all the same. multiple files, multiple different hashes.

Comment: This is strange... Have you opened them in the normal windows editor? If yes, compare the bottom line of the Editor. There you can see the file encoding. If they are the same, can you use CryptoJS on the server too? I had the problem in Java. I had one method to create a checksum on my client, and another one on the server. They were slightly different, I still don't know why. So I copied one of them to the other side and after that it worked for me.

Comment: yeah, they are the same file.. ill using cryptojs after work.

Comment: just could not get it to work with CryptoJS no matter what I did, but I tried another package called 'browser-md5-file' that works perfectly first try. wanted to leave some thing here in case anyone else had the same problem